# Cairos's configure output: Is it enough for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, configure, gtk3

I intend to compile Firefox from the source. For that, I do need to compile GTK. And for that, I do need to compile Cairo.

After solving some of Cairo's dependencies, I was able to run the configure script. Bellow, the result:

```
cairo (version 1.10.2 [release]) will be compiled with:

The following surface backends:
Image:         yes (always builtin)
Recording:     yes (always builtin)
Tee:           no (disabled, use --enable-tee to enable)
XML:           no (disabled, use --enable-xml to enable)
Skia:          no (disabled, use --enable-skia to enable)
Xlib:          yes
Xlib Xrender:  no (requires  http://freedesktop.org/Software/xlibs)
Qt:            no (disabled, use --enable-qt to enable)
Quartz:        no (requires CoreGraphics framework)
Quartz-image:  no (disabled, use --enable-quartz-image to enable)
XCB:           no (disabled, use --enable-xcb to enable)
Win32:         no (requires a Win32 platform)
OS2:           no (disabled, use --enable-os2 to enable)
CairoScript:   no (disabled, use --enable-script to enable)
PostScript:    yes
PDF:           yes
SVG:           yes
OpenGL:        no (disabled, use --enable-gl to enable)
BeOS:          no (disabled, use --enable-beos to enable)
DirectFB:      no (disabled, use --enable-directfb to enable)
OpenVG:        no (disabled, use --enable-vg to enable)
DRM:           no (disabled, use --enable-drm to enable)

The following font backends:
  User:          yes (always builtin)
  FreeType:      no (freetype-config not found in path or $FREETYPE_CONFIG)
  Fontconfig:    no (freetype-config not found in path or $FREETYPE_CONFIG)
  Win32:         no (requires a Win32 platform)
  Quartz:        no (requires CoreGraphics framework)

The following functions:
  PNG functions:   yes
  GLEW functions:  no (not required by any backend)
  GLX functions:   no (not required by any backend)
  WGL functions:   no (not required by any backend)
  EGL functions:   no (not required by any backend)
  X11-xcb functions: no (disabled, use --enable-xlib-xcb to enable)
  XCB-drm functions: no (disabled, use --enable-xcb-drm to enable)
  XCB-shm functions: no (requires --enable-xcb)
  DRM-Xr functions: no (disabled, use --enable-drm-xr to enable)

The following features and utilities:
   cairo-trace:                yes
   cairo-script-interpreter:   yes

And the following internal features:
  pthread:       yes
  gtk-doc:       no
  gcov support:  no
  symbol-lookup: no (requires bfd)
  test surfaces: no (disabled, use --enable-test-surfaces to enable)
  ps testing:    no (requires libspectre)
  pdf testing:   no (requires poppler-glib >= 0.13.3)
  svg testing:   no (requires librsvg-2.0 >= 2.15.0)


*** No native font backends enabled for your platform. It is strongly
*** recommended that you enable the native font backend feature for your
*** platform.
```

I am asking that mainly due to the warn above. Are those FreeType, FontType or Quartz really necessary (having Firefox in mind)? Anything else that would be nice to have? Thanks for the input.